# disabling the button for this particular form

Tags: angular

How to disable the button for a single group in a form? Currently when I dirty the control both buttons (save and hidden) become active.
Using

```
[disabled]="!cappingForm.dirty"
```

doesn't work because when I dirty one control all the buttons are unlocked, while there should be one. How to refer to the specific form I am using?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qd7vym?fbclid=IwAR29etqG_Zm3wZ9X6E70hRJBeIpskbLh1B0_GpYwD8cy-T8bM0xeWwt0GH0&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specific formGroup that you need by using `this.cappingForm.get(template.name)`

modify the condition to

```
[disabled]="!this.cappingForm.get(template.name).dirty"
```

Full example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brjwwo?file=src/app/app.component.html)